# Is there a term for the combination of sexism and ageism?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, idiom-requests, gender-politics

For example, calling Clinton "Grandma" though Trump is older,
 higher unemployment in Britain of women 50-64 seeking work than men,
men seen as desirable at the same age women are seen as desperate, gender gap in media roles for same age.

This can be described as "prejudice", but what I seek is a way to pinpoint this particular toxic combination.

Comment: How about prejudice?

Comment: true, but what I seek is a way to pinpoint this toxic combination

Comment: Sageism? No, I suppose not…

Comment: @JanusB - This seems like a good place for a newly-minted portmanteau. Too bad yours won't work.

Comment: @J.R. 'Newly-minted portmanteau', 'This seems like a good place for' and 'English Language and **Usage**' don't sit together very well. As Nohat has said: "While I'm not entirely opposed to “single word requests” I get pretty anxious when I see questions like this one, where there is (to my knowledge) no real answer, and then people take this as an invitation to start coining words.'

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet,I thought of that too, it's almost too accurate.

Comment: I get pretty nervous when I see the actual phenomenon I describe, but I guess I am barking up the wrong tree.  Internet search for a term led me here. Raised by English professors and a questioner, ,fan of slang, and seeker of the perfect bon mot I would rather coin words than hold my tongue. . Hope I can answer other questions though "on hold"'. I did share to FB